# .htaccess file ignored on Ubuntu server

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, htaccess

I'm having a problem with an `.htaccess` file on a newly installed Ubuntu server running Apache2.

The .htaccess file in the directory where the WordPress files are located isn't being take into account when the server loads pages.  There isn't an `AllowOverride` statement in the apache2.conf file, but the default is `All`, and it doesn't change anything if I include one.

I've tried including the contents of the local `.htaccess` file in a  section.  I've also tried this:

```
<Directory /var/www/mydomain.com/html>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

I also tried changing all instances of `AllowOverride` in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default (which are all set to `None`by default) to `All`.

But I've had no luck.

Not sure how to solve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure the mod_rewrite is enabled:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Then restart apache

Comment: Actually, I'd checked: it was already enabled.  But I eventually found what was causing it! See below.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out what it was since I opened this thread: there were two issues that I would have thought would crop up in any vanilla LAMP setup installed according to the [Media Temple Knowledgebase article](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28ve%29:Install_LAMP_on_Ubuntu_9.10) (which was what I used to set up the [(ve) server](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/ve/)).

Firstly,  it was the rewrite module. It appeared as though my `.htaccess` files weren’t being read by the server because a rewrite module has to be enabled: this seems to be the default on a fresh install such as the one I just carried out. Who knew?

Enabling the module is pretty simple: I just needed to make a symbolic link to the `rewrite.load` file from the mods-available directory to the mods-enabled directory (all found, in this instance, in the apache2 directory, at `/etc/apache2`).

Ran the following:

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
$ ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/rewrite.load rewrite.load
```

Secondly, I concluded I also need to change all instances of `AllowOverride` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` (which are all set to `None` by default) to `All`(see [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/278610/apache2-rewriterule-not-working) which explains the issue).

Finally was the question of how to apply the rules.  I actually chose to delete my .htaccess file and place all its rules in a `<Directory>` section in `http.conf` (which is now a separate file still called in apache2.conf, and which I'll use to include all my customizations), because setting `AllowOverride` to `None` and relying on `apache2.conf` for everything induces an increase in speed as the server no longer has to check for an `.htaccess` file at every level before loading a page.  I then deleted the `.htaccess`, set `AllowOverride`to `None`, and the rules still loaded fine.

Comment: Note that the a2enmod command under ubuntu creates the symbolic link for you.  It is always good to understand what is going on behind the scenes, but if you do, then using the command will avoid any type errors